# React setState syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

My question is pretty straight forward, I've found the state being updated in a few places like this and am wondering why would we use this syntax:

```
const showFlagRev = this.state.showFlag;
this.setState({showFlag: !showFlagRev});
```

Over this syntax:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({showFlag: !prevState.showFlagRev}));
```

Is there any reason to this or is this just a old (maybe clearer?) way of update the state in a React application?

Any references (docs, articles, examples) are much appreciated!

Comment: The second snippet won't work, you probably meant `this.setState(prevState => ({ showFlag: !prevState.showFlagRev }));` The first snippet is just more long-winded, and unnecessarily so imo. It's also fine to do just `this.setState({ showFlag: !this.state.showFlag })`

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot the (), thanks for pointing it out, I will update the question right now. As for using ```this.setState({ showFlag: !this.state.showFlag })``` I remember reading that this is not recommended, do you have any references to back up your claim? Thank you!

Comment: @Nick09: Just to clarify, `this.setState({ showFlag: !this.state.showFlag })` is 100% the same as your first example. Assigning the state value to variable first doesn't change its behavior.

Comment: Thank you Felix, please change your answer to reflect this and I will accept it since this is all I wanted to confirm. Your current answer is just explaining why we need to use prevState, but what I asked is what is the difference between those two syntax's and why we would prefer one over the other!

Comment: Or if you think my question isn't clear enough please feel free to help out with an edit or let me know its not clear and I will try to edit it myself :), thank you!

Comment: I can't imagine you read that this isn't recommended; it's perfectly fine to do that. What you *aren't* supposed to do is mutate state directly, i.e. `this.state.showFlag = !this.state.showFlag;` then `this.setState({ showFlag });`. However I'm not doing that at all, using `this.state.showFlag` in an expression won't change its value. (didn't downvote btw)

Comment: @Chris G I've managed to locate the article in which I read about this and it makes perfect sens, you can take a look here: https://medium.com/better-programming/3-mistakes-junior-developers-make-with-a-react-components-state-997043291b54 on the second point if you want to read about it!

Comment: I thought your question is primarily about using an additional variable vs. not doing it, rather than using a function vs. not using one. Like Felix said, using the function makes sure that multiple state changes in quick succession don't give a wrong result, so yes, use a function if you want to make sure of that. I never do that unless it makes sense, loading state data from an API when your app mounts for instance doesn't require a function obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> This form of `setState()` is also asynchronous, and multiple calls during the same cycle may be batched together. For example, if you attempt to increment an item quantity more than once in the same cycle, that will result in the equivalent of:

```
Object.assign(
  previousState,
  {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
  {quantity: state.quantity + 1},
  ...
)
```

> Subsequent calls will override values from previous calls in the same cycle, so the quantity will only be incremented once. If the next state depends on the current state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
});
```